# Emacs indentation screwed up

Tags: emacs

I recently upgraded to emacs 24.3.1 in order to use a new mode for programming in D.  I seem to have introduced some problem with my other modes now (Java, C++ C I'm just using whatever comes with emacs). When I scroll up/down in a buffer, the text displayed is totally messed up. As in lines mixed together, indentation screwy, cursor not modifying where it looks like it is.  If I hit ctrl-l the screen refreshes and all is good.  I noticed this problem every once in a while with my previous version when editing C .h files.  But now it's happening on every single buffer. I can't work with it. Every time I move up/down I have to refresh the screen.  I can't find anything similar to my problem with a google search.  Might end up being an issue with some incompatible version of a dependency.  Here's my system stats.

CentOS release 5.4 (Final)

linux 2.6.18-164.el5

emacs 24.3.1

I don't even know what other libs emacs might depend on.  I'll be happy to post versions of anything that might be relevant.

Thanks

Comment: Reproducible with `emacs -Q`?

Comment: I tried with -Q and -nw.  Still happens with both.

Comment: Could be something wrong with the binary. Try to compile emacs24-3 from source.

Comment: This was built from source, but I just went ahead and recompiled.  Still happening.

Comment: If you can build from source and reproduce with `emacs -Q` than it's a bug that should be reported with M-x `report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: I'll give that a shot. Reverting back to my previous version.  Thanks.

Comment: Out of interest, what terminal emulator are you using? I'm using terminator, and I've been encountering the same problem over the last week, but it's noticeable on several servers, all with various versions of Ubuntu and Emacs (23/24). I went back to the default terminal in Mint, and it's working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say that this happens also with `emacs -Q`, i.e., without your init file, consider filing a bug report: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.  For that, try to give a short, reprocible recipe, starting with `emacs -Q`.  Emacs Dev will take a look and let you know whether they think there is a bug.

Using `report-emacs-bug` also automatically gathers info about your Emacs version etc., and includes it with your bug description.